# AHK - Extra buttons in my macro

Tags: autohotkey

So I have a few simple macros... Now the one bound to Numpad1 is fine until I start hitting the other two. After a few times of hitting Numpad2 or Numpad3 they will start sending an extra shift command. Now if I manually hit LShift it will "fix" it for a bit but after a few times it will start sending the extra LShift again.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
Numpad1::
    Send {s down}
    Sleep, 33
    Click down
    Sleep, 33
    Click up
    Sleep, 33
    Send {s up}
Return

Numpad2::
    Send {LShift down}
    Sleep, 33
    Click down
    Sleep, 33
    Click up
    Sleep, 33
    Send {LShift up}
Return

Numpad3::
    Send {LShift down}
    Sleep, 33
    Click down right
    Sleep, 33
    Click up right
    Sleep, 33
    Send {LShift up}
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using SendInput instead of Send.